# Pandas time difference calculation error

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have two time columns in my dataframe: called date1 and date2.
As far as I always assumed, both are in date_time format. However, I now have to calculate the difference in days between the two and it doesn't work.

I run the following code to analyse the data:

```
df['month1'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date1']).month
df['month2'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date2']).month
print(df[["date1", "date2", "month1", "month2"]].head(10))
print(df["date1"].dtype)
print(df["date2"].dtype)
```

The output is:

```
    date1         date2     month1  month2
0 2016-02-29   2017-01-01       1       1
1 2016-11-08   2017-01-01       1       1
2 2017-11-27   2009-06-01       1       6
3 2015-03-09   2014-07-01       1       7
4 2015-06-02   2014-07-01       1       7
5 2015-09-18   2017-01-01       1       1
6 2017-09-06   2017-07-01       1       7
7 2017-04-15   2009-06-01       1       6
8 2017-08-14   2014-07-01       1       7
9 2017-12-06   2014-07-01       1       7
datetime64[ns]
object
```

As you can see, the month for date1 is not calculated correctly! 
The final operation, which does not work is:

```
df["date_diff"] = (df["date1"]-df["date2"]).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

which leads to the following error:

```
incompatible type [object] for a datetime/timedelta operation
```

I first thought it might be due to date2, so I tried:

```
df["date2_new"] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'] - 315619200, unit = 's')
```

leading to:

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Anyone has an idea what I need to change?

Comment: Are both date1 and date2 in date_time when you read it ? or did you convert them to date_time with unit='m' ?

Comment: `date2` is still a column of string dates. You should first convert them to datetime objects before doing anything, and then once that has been done properly, you can get the months with `df.col_name.dt.month` I don't understand why you are subtracting a number from `date2` and using seconds if it's in the format of your first table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .dt accessor with `days` attribute:

```
df[['date1','date2']] = df[['date1','date2']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df['date_diff'] = (df['date1'] - df['date2']).dt.days
```

Output:

```
       date1      date2  month1  month2  date_diff
0 2016-02-29 2017-01-01       1       1       -307
1 2016-11-08 2017-01-01       1       1        -54
2 2017-11-27 2009-06-01       1       6       3101
3 2015-03-09 2014-07-01       1       7        251
4 2015-06-02 2014-07-01       1       7        336
5 2015-09-18 2017-01-01       1       1       -471
6 2017-09-06 2017-07-01       1       7         67
7 2017-04-15 2009-06-01       1       6       2875
8 2017-08-14 2014-07-01       1       7       1140
9 2017-12-06 2014-07-01       1       7       1254
```

Comment: This answer works fine for me, but may I ask why month1 is still not displayed correctly?

Comment: I think would redefine `df['month1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1']).dt.month` and like wise with df['month2'].  You're use of pd.DatetimeIndex is somewhat unconventional.  However, testing it appear your logic should work.  Not sure why you are getting back the incorrect months.